# update syntax in mysql equivalent to Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle

In oracle i have found that we can give all parameters in one go while updating a row like:

```
update table1
set 
(column1,column2,column3,column4,column5) 
= (select 'a','b','c','d','e' from DUAL)
where id=xyz;
```

Is there a way we can achieve this same functionality in mysql too..?

Comment: look at the MySql documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: @davegreen100: but there it was given that i have to give all param value with column name seperately, not in one go,as we are given in oracle

Comment: here you are storing static value like 'a','b','c','d','e'..as per my understanding not fetching any value from table dual...am i right.if yes then you can update table1 simply...update table1 set col1='a', col2='b', col3='c' where id=xyz;

Comment: @kawade, you still have to list the columns just in a different place, in oracle its (col1, col2...) (val1, val2...) and in MySQL its (col1=val1, col2=val2...). So the same amount of typing just different syntax.